# How To Get MySQL Variable Into Where Clause

Tags: mysql, variables

I have query here:

```
select *,@final := DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AS final_date from emp_employee as emp
where employee_type_id=2
and (end_date is null or end_date>now());
```

The result is:
[image]

But when i change my query into this:

```
select *,@final := DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AS final_date from emp_employee as emp
where employee_type_id=2
and YEAR(@final)=2016
and (end_date is null or end_date>now());
```

It didn't give any result, it is null. What's wrong with my query and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your query in the following way

```
select *, DATE_ADD(emp.start_date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AS final_date from emp_employee as emp
where emp.employee_type_id=2
and YEAR(DATE_ADD(emp.start_date, INTERVAL 2 YEAR))=2016
and (ISNULL(emp.end_date) or emp.end_date>now());
```

You must use `ISNULL` function to check if a particular column has NULL value.